# tips to reduce message traffic and size in order to have less download amount

Tags: web-services, windows-mobile

I have a mobile application integrated to a server where users can see tasks assigned and close the task request after work. In this project timing is very important, at least ones in a minute program should check if a task is assigned. Moreover mobile should also check the server if there is a change on the task that it already downloaded.

Because of the nature of the project download amount is high. How can we reduce it? Should we use another technology for server communication (Now we use ASP.NET Web Service Application)?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use push notifications instead of polling.

Answer (score 1):

Use JSON instead of XML Server.

Try using selective sync options like instead of complete tasks sync as it would become slow with higher number of tasks.

Mark task changes locally on mobile. mark entities dirty and then only update marked tasks to cloud/Server.

as SLaks suggested use push instead of pull it will save mobile battery and user's data package.

Here is what can help you:
Microsoft Sync Framework.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/sync/bb887608.aspx

http://weblogs.aspnet05.orcsweb.com/sbehera/archive/2009/04/10/sync-framework-for-windows-mobile-devices-amp-some-use-full-links.aspx

Comment: Would you happen to know a site that has a good tutorial or example of this?

Comment: Last year i have developed a WP7 app that was actually a TODO list app. I used all these methods on that app. it was using Azure blob storage to store tasks and tasks list on cloud. i will have to check for a proper turotial

Comment: i have added some tutorials with Microsoft Sync as it is a very trending option.